# What should I do with comments that need to be edited?

Tags: discussion, comments, edits

I have reputation 521, I can edit question and answer but not a comment. There is very helpful, but mistyped comment. Only one letter need to be changed. Should I flag it? I have no right do anything else.

Let us see the example:

There is a question:
[Where is @Html.MailTo in MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190779/where-is-html-mailto-in-mvc-4/14191182#14191182)

And the most usefull part of the answer for me is the comment: "marked up with a helper attribute e.g. [DataType(DataTypes.EmailAddress)]"

But it should be DataType.EmailAddress instead of DataTypes.EmailAddress.

I would like to delete the mistyped s, but I cannot. What should I do?

Comment: write a comment with a polite correction

Comment: Write a comment for editing the correct comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you do absolutely nothing. Since the ability to comment was introduced, comments have been considered 2nd class citizens, and have no edit history at all (so you can't see what was changed and when and by whom).

There is virtually no capability to edit comments for regular users, the only exception being the original author of the comment can edit it at will for 5 minutes after it was posted.  You cannot edit anyone else's comment ever, regardless of reputation.

Moderators can edit comments, but this not a common practice and usually only done for serious issues (such as a useful comment that is very rude or offensive).  Small typos or grammar mistakes are often not changed, simply because it would be a full time job for a moderator to worry about cleaning things up.

The best thing to do if you encounter a typo in a comment that potentially can cause confusion is to leave your own comment and ask "@bobLoblaw do you mean .....?".

For the kinds of typos, I'm thinking of things such as:

1. Forgetting a "not" or other typo/omission that causes the comment to say something other than what you think it was intended to mean
2. A serious spelling mistake that changes the meaning of a post
3. A significant typo in a code snippet that would have a different result than what is being intended.

Minor stuff like a missing "s" or a using its instead of it's should just be left alone.

Don't flag a comment for moderator attention to correct a typo unless the issue is so serious that it needs to be fixed.  Moderators have enough flags to handle, so they don't need a whole host of new ones asking them to capitalize "i" in thousands of comments.

Answer (score 3):

In this situation you edit it into the answer.

If the answer is incorrect and corrected in a comment, which is itself incorrect then correcting the comment seems more than a little ridiculous. Add all the information into the answer instead and everything's in one place.

**Be careful** doing this. People sometimes don't like editing of code. Ensure that your edit summary states that you're moving useful information from a comment into the post and I would link to the documentation that proves you're correct. I know nothing about the subject so I'm not making the edit myself.

Don't be upset if your edit gets rejected. If it does all shrug your shoulders and move on; it's only an "s" after all; you'd hope people would work it out if they copied and pasted the code and got an error.

If your edit is approved you can flag all the comments as obsolete and help keep the place that little bit cleaner.